# Trigger to check if the Close Date is changed is not working

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

I created a Trigger on Opportunity which checks if the CloseDate field is changed and Sets aCounter to see how many times it has changed. I created custom numeric field whose default value is 0. Created the trigger below

```
trigger OppPusher on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
  if (system.trigger.isInsert) {
    for (Opportunity o : trigger.new) {
      o.PushCount__c = 0;
    }
  } else {
    for (Opportunity o : trigger.new) {
      if (o.CloseDate != null &&
        system.trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).CloseDate != null &&
        o.CloseDate > system.trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).CloseDate) {
        if(o.PushCount__c ==NULL)
            o.PushCount__c =1; 
         else
            o.PushCount__c += 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is on the Opportunity creation I am seeing the PushCount__c  is set 2 not sure why. All I need to just increment the PushCount__c by 1 only when the Close Date fiel is updated. Can anyone please suggest me what I am missing here.

Comment: do you have workflows or process builders that do field updates on the Opportunity hence re-firing the before update trigger? This would be the most likely reason and you'll need to implement a trigger guard - static set<id> hasPushedIds

Comment: @cropredy Can you please help with how can I use the trigger guard here

Comment: Please review this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332407&type=1&mode=1. Also, one of the approach can be to set a default value of the number field to 1 if you are not exposing it on the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a trigger recursion guard

```
trigger OppPusher on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
  if (Trigger.isInsert) {
    for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
      o.PushCount__c = 0;
    }
  } else {  // before update use case
    for (Opportunity o : trigger.new) {
        if (!PushRecursionGuard.ids.contains(o.Id) &&
            o.CloseDate > Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).CloseDate) {
        PushRecursionGuard.ids.add(o.Id);
        if(o.PushCount__c ==NULL) {o.PushCount__c =1;} 
        else {o.PushCount__c += 1;}
      }
    }
  }
}

public class PushRecursionGuard {
  public static Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
}
```

The [best practice link in the SFDC help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332407&type=1&mode=1) on static recursion flags is not, in fact, best practice as it fails when you do DML on Opportunity with > 200 records which can occur in various use cases - apex, bulk api, platform event subscribers, ...

Hence, I used a set of Ids that is not bounded by 200